# How do you search all items via Exchange IMAP?

Tags: email, exchange-server, imap, exchangewebservices

I am trying to perform an IMAP `uid_search` against an exchange server (office 365) to find all emails to/from a particular email address. The problem is that some clients have a prohibitively large number of folders.

Using active sync, it appears that there is an `All Items` folder that can search all emails at once: [Exchange Web Services (EWS) FindItems within All Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401080/exchange-web-services-ews-finditems-within-all-folders), however, I do not see the same folder in the IMAP folder list and am having to perform the query against each folder individually.

Is there a way to search all emails in exchange using IMAP without having to search each folder?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to an Exchange IMAP server, so I don't have any concrete answer that I can give you.

Instead, I'll have to provide you with some suggestions to look into to answer your own question.

1. Does Exchange IMAP support the [XLIST](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#xlist_is_deprecated) or [SPECIAL-USE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6154) IMAP extensions? If so, you can use one of those to query for an "All Items" folder. Unfortunately, I doubt it supports either of those.
2. Does Exchange IMAP support the [MULTISEARCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6237) extension? If so, you can use that to search multiple folders at once.

If it doesn't support any of those IMAP extensions, then you are probably out of luck unless they have a custom extension (I doubt it).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, none of those extensions are supported. Might have to abandon IMAP for exchange.