# How to search items across folders in office 365 using EWS Java API

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365, ewsjavaapi

I'm trying to search items across folders in office 365 using EWS Java API.

I'm using EWS Java API 1.3 version (https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api)

I have seen the following link and tried like that in Java but still this one also not working

[Exchange Web Services (EWS) FindItems within All Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401080/exchange-web-services-ews-finditems-within-all-folders)

Regards
Ramesh

Comment: "but still this one also not working" **What** does not work?

Comment: Hi @Rams  were you able to get it working? Even I am also trying to do something similar. But I am failing terribly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425697/connect-to-outlook-2013-through-java-api

Answer (score 1):

In 2013 and Office365 the best thing to use to search a Mailbox is eDiscovery which you can use from EWS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190897(v=exchg.150).aspx . There is nothing in the Java API to use the eDiscovery SOAP operations so you would need to either build those yourself or use raw SOAP or generate some proxyclass to use it.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: My application currently supports Exchange 2010 SP2, but the search is horrendously slow. Have you tried this yourself? I'm very eager to try it out!